# How does a pdo detect that there is no column in the database

Tags: php, pdo

How does pdo detect that there is no column in a database. thanks

Comment: Maybe you could supply just a *little* more background story to this question...?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'table';
```

It will return a list of all columns in `table`, if none are returned, there are no columns.

Answer (score 1):

It's not actually PDO but database server. PDO send your query to the server and get an error from it.